# How to export 1 Entries type ("news") from Craft to Wordpress

Tags: csv, export

I have a lot of News entries in a Craft 2.6.2990 website that I would like to export and then import into Wordpress.
Most of the advice out there is for doing this the other way round.
I need Title, Post content, featured image and date created for each entry.

I am thinking that I should be using the Sprout plugin to export to a csv file. Can anyone offer any advice on this and confirm if this is the right way to go about it? I am not very familiar with Craft.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Most people are going the other way. Is there a particular reason you want to downgrade? ;-)

Being serious though...

If you need the entries in a CSV format then yes you could use an export plugin such as Sprout or Export. Or you could make a template that outputs your content in the format required.

If you choose a plugin, then you'd need to read the documentation to find out how to set that up.

As for importing into Wordpress. That's dependent on your Wordpress setup and what you are using to do the import and is probably outside the scope of this particular Stack Exchange site.

But bear in mind that Craft is incredibly flexible so if the reason you're wanting to switch is related to particular functionality it could almost certainly be achieved with Craft.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Don't want to get pelted here, but my experience of Craft has put me off it and I much prefer Wordpress!! I've got the import to Wordpress part covered OK, it's just getting out of Craft that I'm struggling with.

Comment: I'm now unsure how to get the Sprout plugin into Craft. On the Sprout website I can see a link to download that goes to github. From that page, you can download a zip file. But it's still unclear if I upload that zipped folder, or part of it? Sorry for the very basic questions - it's probably very obvious to you...

Comment: unzip it and you should get a folder named something like 'sprout'. Put that in the craft/plugins directory. Then go to the craft dashboard->settings->plugins and install it

Answer (score 1):

I did install the Sprout Reports but found the user interface to be very challenging, not at all obvious to me how to go about getting what I wanted. 
In the end, I installed Boboldehampsink Export plugin for Craft 2. This was much easier to use and I got most of my data out that way. The missing piece I was able to export direct from the database using SQL. 
https://github.com/boboldehampsink/export
Thanks for the help!